# how to get stdout of child process in realtime?

Tags: c++, linux, popen

I want to catch stdout of child task in realtime, my child task is created by popen. But I found my code has a large delay.
Below is my example:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#define BUFF_LEN (16*1024)
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char *buf = (char*)malloc(BUFF_LEN);
    char cmd[128];
    sprintf(cmd, "while true;do echo gg;sleep 1;done");
    FILE *out = popen(cmd, "r");
    if(setvbuf(out, NULL, _IONBF, 0)) perror("setvbuf");
    while(1){
        int len = fread(buf, 1, BUFF_LEN, out);
        if(len < 0){
            cout << "read error" << endl;
            continue;
        }
        write(1, buf, len);
    }
}
```

I have tried setvbuf but without luck. If I remove "sleep 1" then the output is quick. There must be somewhere else doing the buffering. How to make it working?

Answer (score 0):

After popen, you can do :

```
if (fcntl(fileno(out), F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK) < 0)
        exit(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know why now. I have to call setvbuf in child process, not parent.